# Unable to sort by column of apache POI pivot table

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73655197/230513), I am generating the pivot table using the apache POI. When the excel sheet is generated with pivot table, I want it to sort the column which is showing the months data in chronological order by month (ascending). Below is the sample code used to generate the pivot table.

```
XSSFSheet dataSheet
        = workbook.createSheet("DataSheet");
workbook = dataWriteService.writeToSheet(workbook, dataSheet, dataResponseList); //data is written in the sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("PIVOTSHEET");

AreaReference ar = new AreaReference(topLeft, botRight, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
CellReference cr1 = new CellReference("A1");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable1 = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr1, dataSheet);
pivotTable1.addRowLabel(5);
pivotTable1.addRowLabel(12);
pivotTable1.addColLabel(19);
final File xlsFile = new File("dataWithPivot.xlsm");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsFile);
workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
```

Below is the sample code I have been trying to sort pivot table by column and not worked.

```
int indexOfSortColumn = 1;
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition()
        .getPivotFields()
        .getPivotFieldArray(indexOfSortColumn)
        .setSortType(STFieldSortType.ASCENDING);
//below is the second tried approach and didnot work
CTPivotField fld = pivotTable1.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList().get(1);
fld.setSortType(STFieldSortType.ASCENDING);
```

build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-full', version: '5.2.2'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'ooxml-schemas', version: '1.1'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate how this question differs from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73655197/230513) on the topic.

Comment: @trashgod - previous question was denoting more of the exception i was getting which i mentioned in the previous question. This question has no exception but unable to get the expected output. And please if you dont have the proper answer for the question and just to mention that its a previous question reduces the chance of someone looking and answer it.

Comment: You are correct: as I can't reproduce your result, I don't have a proper _answer_ for the question; my _comment_ was for the convenience of someone who might have an answer.

Comment: Why do you think that `indexOfSortColumn` should be `1`? Shouldn't that be "the column which is showing the months data"? So, either `5`, `12` or `19`?